# Why the isometry $f$ must be a translation when it satisfies $\text{d}(f(x),x) < K$ for some $K > 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, isometry

Let $f$ be an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

And, let's say $f$ satisfies $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\text{d}(f(x),x) < K$ for some $K > 0$.

My attemtpt:

Every isometry could be expressed as $t\circ g$ where $t$ is a translation, and $g$ is an orthogonal transformation.

So, let $f(x) = t\circ g (x)$, and see what happens if $g \neq I$.

By assuming $g \neq I$, we can get a line where $g(x)$ and $x$ belongs to.

Now, by $t$, we will get $t(g(x))=g(x)+a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I also applied $g$ once again to $g(x)$.

At this point, I tried to draw each point and tried to use the triangle inequality to intuitively see the relationships between points (when $g$ is not identity.) However, I couldn't get any useful information from the drawing. Also, it made me even more confused.

What should I consider for this problem?

**Edit:**

I've been trying to see what gives me a contradiction by letting $a=0$ as "Moishe Kohan" suggested.

But, I'm still stuck. Using the triangle inequality didn't really help. Drawing also didn't.

However, there's one I found, which is $|a| < K$. I got it from plugging in $x=0$. (I'm not sure if this would be useful though.)

May I have more hints to go further?

Comment: Hint: First work out the case of identity  translation part.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You mean, the translation $T$ which is defined by $T(x) = x + 0$?

Comment: I mean $a=0$ in your formula, but $g$ is some orthogonal transformation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I still don't see the big picture clear, but one thing interesting was the isosceles triangle that I could get from $x,f(x),ff(x)$. Can I get some more hints?

Comment: Draw pictures in the plane. And forget about iterations of $f$, they do not help.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Would considering $|x|>K$ help?

Comment: Try to prove it then first for $n=1$. Is there an upper bound on $d(gx, x)$ ? Why not? If you manage, then try $n=2$. Does the same reasoning as in the case $n=1$ apply here? If it does, try the same reasoning in the case $n\ge 3$.